# TCL: What package forget command actually does?

Tags: tcl

Can anyone Help me in understanding "package forget" command in TCL .

The TCL manual says that

> `package forget ?package package ...?`
>   Removes all information about each specified package from this interpreter, including
>   information provided by both `package ifneeded` and `package provide`.

As per my understanding after executing the package forget command on a perticular package the commands those are available in that package should not be executed.

Is it like that ?

And also please explain the `package unknown` command ?

Comment: I just ran a test on 8.4 and **package forget** isn't really forgetting; though, the command did remove the entry from the list returned by **package names**. I can still load and call on commands belonging to a package that was allegedly forgotten.  What version are you working with?

Answer (score 3):

The Tcl package mechanism is simple:

When you do `package require SomePackage` then Tcl will look if it knows something about that package.

- If it is already loaded (an earlier call to `package provide`) it will just return the version number.
- If it is not yet loaded but it knows how to load it (by a previous call to `package ifneeded`) it will execute that script, does some checks (the package should be loaded, versions must match...) and return the version.
- If it does know nothing about the package, it will execute `package unknown` which knows how it can find packages and calls `package ifneeded` for each found package.

A `package forget` will just wipe out any information that an `package provide` and a `package ifneeded` supplied. The actual commands of that package are not removed.

Comment: Where we can find this "package unknown" related configuration ? Can we cutomize it ?

Comment: Sure. A part of it is in a file called tm.tcl, the other part is in package.tcl. Just exectue `package unknown` to see what command is called when a package is not found.

Comment: Or, just set `package unknown` to your own handler cmd: `proc ::MyPkgUnknownHandler {pkg version} {;}; package unknown ::MyPkgUnknownHandler` ... This new command will be called upon `package req foo`, also after having forgotten `foo`.